# php DatePeriod Object access start and current date

Tags: php, date

My understanding is that you cant access start and current date from date period object. My current php is 5.5, is there a workaround, since I cant upgrade to php 5.6 or php 7, and I need to get those dates.

```
DatePeriod Object
(
    [start] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2016-04-03 00:00:00
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => UTC
        )

    [current] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2016-04-10 00:00:00
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => UTC
        )
)
```

Comment: HHVM gives you access to the `current()` and `rewind()` methods for the DatePeriod class, allowing you to access those values; but AFAIK no version of PHP gives you access to them (not even 7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`DatePeriod`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php) is a [`Traversable`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php) interface implementation. It supports only foreach loop.

You can obtain start and current elements only converting it to an array:

```
$start    = new DateTime( '2016-03-01' );
$end      = new DateTime( '2016-03-31' );

$interval = new DateInterval( 'P1D' );
$period   = new DatePeriod( $start, $interval ,$end );

$arPeriod = iterator_to_array( $period );

$startDate   = $arPeriod[0];
next( $arPeriod );
$currentDate = current( $arPeriod );
```